# SQL Server 2008 R2: Find link and chain between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Table:

```
create table tbl_test
(
    col1 int,
    col2 int
);
```

Records:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test 
VALUES (111, 112), (112, 113), (113, 114), (114, 111),
       (115, 116), (117, 118), (118, 119), (111, 130),
       (120, 121), (122, 123), (123, 111),  (124, 111);
```

I need to write 2 different queries for the different output.

**Query 1**: In this query I want to find the link between the `col1` and `col2` in the form of

```
111->112->113->114->111
```

and

```
117->118->119
```

and

```
122->123-111
```

Expected output 1:

```
col1    col2
-------------
111     112
112     113
113     114
114     111
117     118
118     119
122     123
123     111
```

Tried with:

```
SELECT
    col1, col2
FROM 
    tbl_test t
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM tbl_test t1
            WHERE t.col1 = t1.col2
               OR t.col2 = t1.col1)
```

The above query is returning 2 extra record that is `124,111` and `111,130` which should not be displayed because `124` is not in col2 and `130` is not having further link.

**Query 2**: In this query I want to find the complete chain `col1` and `col2` in the form of `111->112->113->114->111` (This is complete chain because it starts with `111` and end with `111`).

Expected output 2:

```
col1    col2
-------------
111     112
112     113
113     114
114     111
```

Comment: Why isn't `122->123->111` continued like `122->123->111->112->113->114->111`?

Comment: @stickybit, It's already there in first 4 records in the query 1 expected result. For query 2 chain will completed only if it starts from same value and end with same.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear there, I was talking about query 1. The last sequence `122->123->111`, why does it end with `111`? I'd guess the first`111->112->113->114->111` is ending with `111` because `111` was already visited by that sequence, but why does `122->123->111` end with `111`?

Comment: I need to display that row because it was there in col2 before it comes to col1. I mean 123.

Comment: `col2` doesn't have values 115 and 117, either.

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sorry, will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

For query1: 
simply find all values, where col2 of one is equal to col1 (of another row, that does not need to be displayed)

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM tbl_test t1 inner join tbl_test t2
ON t1.col2 = t2.col1
```

Query2 is more complicated, because you want to find a chain of entries with infinite number of link entries. If you can restrict the number of chain links, you can find all members having first entry (col1) equal to last entry (col2).

For example: no chain link:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM tbl_test t1 inner join tbl_test t2
ON t1.col2 = t2.col1   AND t2.col2 = t1.col1
```

One chain link (display only starting element of chain):

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM tbl_test t1 inner join tbl_test t2 ON t1.col2 = t2.col1 
inner join tbl_test t3 ON t2.col1 = t3.col1
WHERE t3.col2 = t.col1
```

Comment: Please don't use implicit joins. ANSI SQL fully supports explicit joins for over 25 years now.